# want to drag and replace the element instead of appending every element

Tags: angular

I want to drag and drop a copy of the element, but whenever we drag a new element it should replace the old element.

```
    drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {

    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);     
    } else {
      let item:any = event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex];
      let copy:any = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));
      let element:any = {};
      for(let attr in copy){
        if(attr == 'title') {          
          element[attr] = copy[attr] += ' copy';
        } else{
          element[attr] = copy[attr];
        }       
      }

      this.destination.splice(event.previousIndex,0,element);  
     }
    }
```

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clone-drag-and-drop)

Comment: So you want to move the dragged out element out of the first div and into the second, rather than have a copy in the second div? So the count of objects in the first div decreases by one each time an item is dragged out?

Comment: yes,need to clear the previous element and append the new element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your drop function, just replace

```
//this.destination.splice(event.previousIndex,0,element); //<--replace this
//by 
  this.destination=[element];
```

NOTE: If you use a empty cdkDragPlaceholder you feel better apparence

In your originList

```
<div class="field-box" *ngFor="let item of origin" cdkDrag>{{item.title}}
    <!--add this line -->
      <div *cdkDragPlaceholder ></div>
</div>
```